# MongoDB and Mongoose - UpdateMany, assigning specific values to specific documents

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a schema, similar to:

```
let cat = new Schema({
    _id: {type: String, unique: true, default: shortid.generate},
    name: {type: String, required: true},
    position: {type: Number, required: true}
});
```

All docs have a unique `position`. Therefor, all positions of all docs need to update simultaneously as new docs are inserted or existing docs are rearranged.

To set/rearrange the positions, the user will send something like:

```
let newPos = [
    {id: 1, position: 4}, 
    {id: 2, position: 2}, 
    {id: 3, position: 3}, 
    {id: 4, position: 1}
];
```

Obviously the `id` values would be different, but this is the gist of it.

I know that I can do something like:

```
newPos.forEach((val) => {
    Cat.updateOne({_id: val.id}, {$set: {position: val.position}}, (err, res) => {
        ...
    });
});
```

but can I do the same with [.updateMany()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.updateMany)? From the documentation, it looks like the updates are all the same for all the docs affected, but I'd like to modify certain docs based on their `_id` and predetermined values. It would certainly be easier to determine when all of the updates are complete, opposed to using additional counters.

**Edit #1**

Looks like a (very) similar question was [onced asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20854721/update-multiple-elements-with-different-value-in-mongoose). The top answer was to use a similar `forEach` to what I described above, so that seems to be the way to go. That's how I'll implement it, but by all means feel free to offer up a better way.

Comment: This sounds like a really tough way of modeling your data that's going to cause lots of problems  (like the one you're running into right now!). What's the use case? It might be a little easier to save a different doc that only has a list of positions (or maybe even save all of the Cats in a single doc)

Comment: The order that categories are presented on the public-facing site. The admin can arrange the categories in any order they'd like. No two items can have the same position value. The only other option is to store a single document with all the categories and their positions, and then I only need to update a single doc, opposed to however many individual categories there might be. Creating a collection for a single document breaks my heart.

Comment: Creating a collection for a single doc feel really wrong, but it's definitely closer to the mongo way! A ton of mongo is designed around supporting larger documents & making it easy to access subdocuments. One option here could be to have a single document that only stores the positions and the _ids of the categories, and have the categories remain separate documents that don't know how they're positioned